# need help understanding this code

Tags: javascript, jquery

this code in book [jQuery in action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182323) page 131

i don't understand

***.trigger('adjustName');***

what is adjustName

and Simple explanation for trigger()

thanks :)

```
$('#addFilterButton').click( function() {
    var filterItem = $('<div>')
    .addClass('filterItem')
    .appendTo('#filterPane')
    .data('suffix','.' + (filterCount++));
    $('div.template.filterChooser')
    .children().clone().appendTo(filterItem)
    .trigger('adjustName');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a string, the name of a **custom event** you defined.

E.g. it would trigger the event handler bound by:

```
el.bind('adjustName', function(){...});
```

For more information I suggest to have a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

> Any event handlers attached with `.bind()` or one of its shortcut methods are triggered when the corresponding event occurs. They can be fired manually, however, with the `.trigger()` method. A call to `.trigger()` executes the handlers in the same order they would be if the event were triggered naturally by the user.

---

Without knowing the context of the code, I would say that calling `.trigger()` here has no effect, as it is called on the [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)ed elements and the event handlers are only cloned if `true` is passed to `clone`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the original [jQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) could be helpful?

> Description: Execute all handlers and
>   behaviors attached to the matched
>   elements for the given event type.

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to trigger, or run, an event. For instance if you wanted the code to mimic the clicking of a button, you could write....

```
$("#myButton").trigger('click');
```

This would then run exactly as if you had clicked the button yourself.

'adjustName' is a custom event. So the trigger function is running that custom event. The custom event is assigned using the jQuery bind function.

```
$("#someElement").bind('adjustName', function() {/* Some Code */});
```

You might create a customer event for clarity. Perhaps your application opens a document, so you might want an event called 'openDocument' and 'closeDocument' assigned to the element containing the document.